# React onKeyDown vs onKeyPress

Tags: reactjs

I am looking for Phone number format. when user enters the no. in Input field. It should look like this.
(123)-111-1233
Thanks in advance. Below I am sharing my work. What Should I use onKeyDown or onKeyPress. It's not complete code but I give an Idea where I have to add the function for format the phone no.

```
Class FormInput extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      phone: '',

}    
    this.handleKeyPress=this.handleKeyPress.bind(this);
}
   
 phoneFormat(input){
              // Strip all characters from the input except digits
              input = input.replace(/\D/g,'');
    
              // Trim the remaining input to ten characters, to preserve phone number format
              input = input.substring(0,10);
    
              // Based upon the length of the string, we add formatting as necessary
              var size = input.length;
              if(size == 0){
                      input = input;
              }else if(size < 4){
                      input = '('+input;
              }else if(size < 7){
                      input = '('+input.substring(0,3)+') '+input.substring(3,6);
              }else{
                      input = '('+input.substring(0,3)+') '+input.substring(3,6)+' - '+input.substring(6,10);
              }
              return input;
      }
    
 handleKeyPress(event){
    
        this.setState({});
    
    }
     <input name='phone' type='text' ref="input" placeholder='(___)-___-____'  value={this.state.phone}  onKeyDown={this.handleKeyPress} onChange={this.handleChange}/>


}
```

Comment: I would say "onKeyPress" because "onKeyDown" is used when you need to do something specific while this particular key is pressed.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: You probably actually want to use `onChange` rather than a key listener